# Run PostgreSQL stored procedure from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, database-connection

I have a database in SQL Server which contains collected data during one day, and a database in PostgreSQL with OSM data. I need to modify collected data in order to create reports for my users.

Now, I imagined that somehow call PostgreSQL procedure from SQL Server, pass collected data to PostgreSQL, do something with that data, and return another result set to SQL Server for creating reports.

What is the 'most efficient' way for achieving this? OR, better question atm, what is the way for achieving this functionality?

My idea is to connect SQL Server and PostgreSQL with PostgreSQL ODBC driver, then copy data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL table, run that stored procedure on PostgreSQL, and return data to SQL Server result table. But, it is not scheduled task. Data to be transferred to PostgreSQL contains latitude, longitude and bearing for about 2-3 million of rows and function which analyses them requires one per one record, not all at once.

Comment: I want to know too. But currently I use a Proxy .net app to move data from one to another. So not sure if exists a direct way, hope learn something new today. Btw similar app, I have avl data from MSQL and passed to Postgress to paint the map.

Comment: I just find this one. Maybe help http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18571.how-to-transfer-records-from-sql-server-to-postgres.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My way is using C# and npgsql to connect to postgres.

I create an app:

1. check SQL Server every min.
2. check Postgres for the last id inserted.
3. create a dataset from MSQL with the news ids
4. insert the new records into Postgres.
5. run postgres store procedure to generata new data
6. create separated webservice to consume the report generated on postgres.

Comment: I am stuck at first steps. Because I'm new to MS BIDS and SSIS, how even you transfer table from SQL Server to PostgreSQL? Can you be thorough, please?